# An implication of the Fierz identity

Tags: group-theory, yang-mills

On page 487 in Schwartz' "Quantum Field Theory and the Standard Model,"
it says that in $SU(N$) the Fierz identity of the form
$$ \sum_a T^a_{ij}T^a_{kl} = \frac{1}{2}\left( \delta_{il}\delta_{kj} -
 \frac{1}{N} \delta_{ij}\delta_{kl}\right) $$
implies
$$\operatorname{tr}[T^a A]\operatorname{tr}[T^a B] = \frac{1}{2} \left[ \operatorname{tr}(AB) - \frac{1}{N} \operatorname{tr}(A)\operatorname{tr}(B)\right]$$
for any $A$ and $B.$

This seems like it should be really obvious, but I don't see how the Fierz identity implies this last equation. What is a starting point for showing this implication?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By definition of trace you have

$$\operatorname{tr}[T^a A] = T^a_{ij}A_{ji}$$

so

$$\operatorname{tr}[T^a A]\operatorname{tr}[T^a B] = \frac{1}{2}\left( \delta_{il}\delta_{kj}A_{ji}B_{lk} -
 \frac{1}{N} \delta_{ij}\delta_{kl}A_{ji}B_{lk}\right)= \frac{1}{2}\left( A_{ji}B_{ij} -
 \frac{1}{N} A_{ii}B_{kk}\right)=\frac{1}{2} \left[ \operatorname{tr}(AB) - \frac{1}{N} \operatorname{tr}(A)\operatorname{tr}(B)\right]$$